# How to force AfxMessageBox to center on mainframe and not whatever child window that currently has focus

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm developing an MDI application, the primary document is maximized in the MDI frame.  I create a non-modal dialog pop-up to display secondary information to the user while they work in the main window.  However, when the user moves the pop-up it takes focus which is expected.  The problem occurs when this window has focus and an event which generates an AfxMessageBox occurs in the mainframe.  I would expect the AfxMessageBox to pop-up centered on the mainframe. Currently, it pops up centered on the non-modal dialog pop-up window which, by chance, had focus at that time.

Is there a way to force AfxMessageBox to always pop-up centered on the mainframe?  Or at least force it to pop-up centered on the window in which it was called.  For example, if in my non-modal dialog an error occurs, i would want the AfxMessageBox to appear centered on that dialog because it's intuitive that the error occurred there.  Alternatively, if I'm working with the non-modal dialog and an error occurs in the mainframe or document then I would like the AfxMessageBox to appear centered on it's view/frame despite the fact that I'm currently working with the child window.

I hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Use the CWnd::MessageBox() method instead.

Comment: I used this as a test and it worked perfectly.  However, we are using Prof-UIS so I used their CExtMessageBox::DoMsgBox() to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Keep using `AfxMessageBox` but override [DoMessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf7k5hh8%28VS.80%29.aspx) of your CWinApp subclass. In your override do whatever you want to display a message box to the user using `::MessageBox()` or even displaying a custom dialog box. This saves you from replacing calls to `AfxMessageBox` across your source code files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use instead standard ::MessageBox with first (parent) parameter equals to NULL.
In this case desktop will be used as parent, so it would be centered on screen.