# How can I force a modeless dialogue to close?

Tags: mfc

I have seen a similar question here:

[How to close a modeless MFC dialog in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039359/how-to-close-a-modeless-mfc-dialog-in-c)

This is how I close my modeless dialogue:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnDestroy()
{
    if (m_pAssignHistoryDlg != NULL)
    {
        delete m_pAssignHistoryDlg;
        m_pAssignHistoryDlg = NULL;
    }

    CDialogEx::OnDestroy();
}
```

This has always been sufficient, until today. What I have found out (quote by chance) is that if the modeless dialogue has a message box up, and the user goes and closes the **parent** dialogue, the modeless dialogue stays on screen until you close the message box.

The modelless dialogue is clearly still within an event handler since it has just performed some action and displayed the results to the user.

Is it possible to force it to shut? Or should I somehow stop my parent dialogue from being closed whilst the modelless popup is on screen?

What is the right thing to do?

Thank you.

**Update:**

I tried this:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnDestroy()
{
    if (m_pAssignHistoryDlg != NULL)
    {
        CWnd *pPopupMessage = m_pAssignHistoryDlg->GetWindow(GW_ENABLEDPOPUP);
        if (pPopupMessage != NULL)
            pPopupMessage->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
        delete m_pAssignHistoryDlg;
        m_pAssignHistoryDlg = NULL;
    }
    CDialogEx::OnDestroy();
}
```

It didn't work. When I debugged, it refused to process that call etc until I had dismissed the popup message box myself.

Things are further complicated by the fact the the modelless dialogue makes use of two message boxes:

1. Are you sure you want to delete the name? YES | NO
2. Name deleted OK

Either the code can be changed to work, or if I go the custom message route I need to know the result of the message box before my code can proceed (for scenario 1).

**Update 2:**

I am now confused. I added a custom registered message in the parent dialogue:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnDisplayMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return AfxMessageBox((LPCTSTR)wParam, (UINT)lParam);
}
```

The modeless dialogue invokes it like this:

```
iResult = ::SendMessage(GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), UWM_DISPLAY_MESSAGE_MSG,
    (WPARAM)strEntry.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);
strEntry.ReleaseBuffer();
```

I have placed a breakpoint in the message handler so I know it is being fired correctly. And indeed a message box is being displayed.

But for some reason, the message box is still showing central to the modeless dialogue and not the editor. I don't understand why?

**Result!**

I found this topic: [How to force AfxMessageBox to center on mainframe and not whatever child window that currently has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882582/how-to-force-afxmessagebox-to-center-on-mainframe-and-not-whatever-child-window)

I adjusted my code:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnDisplayMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return MessageBox((LPCTSTR)wParam, NULL, (UINT)lParam);
}
```

Now it shows center of the parent dialogue.

I do apologize that this question started of in one direction and ended up with an answer in another direction. I am not sure what we do about that? Technically, the comment to me to use GetWindow didn't seem to work for me. So as such, there is no answer. But by changing my design I have been able to prevent the situation.

**Premature Result**

Whilst the message box showed centered, it affects the subsequent code. Coming up with read allocation errors.

But I have come up with a viable solution now:

```
    GetParent()->EnableWindow(FALSE);
    strEntry.Format(IDS_TPL_SURE_DELETE_FROM_ASSIGN_HIST, psHist->strName);
    if (AfxMessageBox(strEntry, MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDNO)
    {
        GetParent()->EnableWindow(TRUE);
        return;
    }
```

I disable the parent before showing the message box and enable it again once it is dismissed. This prevents the user from closing the main window. They much close the popup message. I will have to go this way for now.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You cannot dismiss a window while it still displays a modal dialog (your message box). You could call [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx) passing `GW_ENABLEDPOPUP`, to find out, whether there are any message box windows open, and close those first. Or simply use that information to prevent the owner from (partially) destroying the window hierarchy.

Comment: I think you have a design flaw here: the modeless dialog is NOT supposed to block its parent, but you DO want to block it if there is a modal popup (message box). May be you shouldn't have a modal child in a modeless parent?

Comment: Well, I do want a modeless dialogue. As the user clicks on controls on the editor, the modeless dialogue dynamically updates with history data. The user can click an entry in this window and it is automatically entered in the editor control that has focus. So, using a modeless dialogue is the right way to go. But, sometimes they want to remove a name from the history list and that is done inside the history window, and I provide feedback to the user via popup message. Perhaps I should have posted a registered user message to the parent and got the parent to display the message box instead.

Comment: @IInspectable, which is best? Do that test and close the popup, or, change application to display the popup via a custom message to editor window.